# Proof of uniform continuity of with sequences of functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of continuous functions such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $R$. Suppose that $x_n \rightarrow x_0$. Prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x_n)=f(x_0)$$

I really don't know where to start on this, can someone help me prove this? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: use the inequality $|f_n(x_n) - f(x_0)| \leq |f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| + |f(x_n) - f(x_0)| \leq ||f_n - f|| + |f(x_n) - f(x_0)|$, and recall that uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. NB: I think there's a typo in your question: should the limit be $n$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly and $f_n$ are continuous, we know $f$ is continuous.  Let $\epsilon>0$.  Since $f_n$ converges uniformly, we can find $N_1$ such that $n\geq N_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon/2$ $\forall x$.  Since $f$ is continuous we can find $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$.  Since $x_n$ converges to $x$ we can find $N_2$ such that  $n\geq N_2$ $\Rightarrow$ $|x_n-x|<\delta$.  Then let $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$.  Then if $n\geq N$, then $|x_n-x|<\delta$ so 
$$\begin{split} |f_n(x_n)-f(x)|&=|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)-f(x_n)-f(x)| \\
&\leq |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-f(x)| \\
&<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon . 
\end{split}$$

Comment: @John Ma Thank you for the edit John